# How to make a smooth stretched grid

Tags: objects

I'm trying to reproduce a curved space-time representation, which correspond to a stretched grid as the picture below

[image]

The grid surface should look as if it's pulled from a single point. Is there a simple way to realize this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start with a plane subdivide it for an uneven number e.g. 11 to have it symmetric around the center vertex.

In *Edit Mode / vertex select* enable [propotional editing](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/proportional_edit.html) <kbd>O</kbd> and set the falloff.

[image]
[image]

Add a grid texture (included in attached .blend) and add a subsurf modifier to make it smooth:
[image]

[image]